# How to use datasets uploaded in azureml to pandas to analyse it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have uploaded a dataset to the AzureMl by microsoft . Now the problem is I want to use that dataset(.csv) in the notebook (also provided by azureml)  . But I can't find a way to do it .
It provides a way to access it by :

```
from azureml import Workspace

ws = Workspace(
    workspace_id='777902b8d48a449091a57d13bfcdfdec',
    authorization_token='c05837974f984e4eb6a4df85a97642dd',
    endpoint='https://studioapi.azureml.net'
)
ds = ws.datasets['temp.csv']
frame = ds.to_dataframe()
```

And when I do a :

```
type(frame)
```

It shows: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

But I want it in a form of CSV . So that I start from beginning . SO, I use :
`frame.to_csv('temp.csv')`

Is there any other way to use the uploaded dataset in pandas in azureml?

Comment: Because you use `ds.to_dataframe()`, it will convert the Azure dataset to a pandas dataframe. Your question is _"Is there any other way to use the uploaded dataset in pandas in azureml?"_, but that is exactly what you have right now. What is your question, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @BenjaVR  I want is as csv only , Like I want to start from scratch , Not already one converted to pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing `ds.to_dataframe()`, you can access the raw text data of the file with `ds.read_as_text()`. You will of course have to parse the text file yourself:

- `ds.to_dataframe()`:
  [image]
- `ds.read_as_text()`:
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Convert to CSV" module and download the dataset.

[image]

To use in Azure Notebooks, in a library that you want to use you can upload the CSV.

[image]

To access in a notebook, you can then reference the file name to read the CSV.

[image]